# Change value of column in whole group

Tags: sql-server

Given Example

[image]

A group is defined via the GRP_ID and the GRP_MAIN set. Orange and green are examples of what it should get. Blue is what we have.

All with the same NAME should be grouped to have the same UNIQUE GRP_ID (unique is important, because there are already some data grouped together) and the MAX or TOP or AVG record should be Marked as GRP_MAIN.

- So my first question is, how can I set a value to a whole group
  column, so I can after group by NAME do GRP_ID = 1
- Secound is, how can I check all existing GRP_ID against a number?
- Third, how to pick the next free number of all existing in GRP_ID?

Comment: That's my current problem I google about 1 hour to find how to set a column in a grouop by to a value, but I didn't find anything. Maybe I searched with wrong parameters, but I wasn't able to achieve anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy this into an empty query window and execute... adapt to your needs...

You should use this query **once** to shuffle your data into a new table with columns für GRP_ID and GRP_MAIN. GRP_ID should be IDENTITY...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(VALUE INT, NAME VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (12,'ab')
,(1,'ab')
,(2,'ab')
,(34,'ab')
,(5,'ab')
,(6,'ab')
,(3,'fg')
,(45,'fg')
,(65,'fg')
,(2,'ht')
,(3,'ht')
,(44,'hh')
,(5,'hh')
,(6,'hh')
,(7,'hh');

WITH DistinctNames AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS Inx, x.NAME
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT NAME
        FROM @tbl      
    ) AS x
)
SELECT dn.Inx AS GRP_ID
      ,CASE WHEN tbl.Value=MainRec.VALUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS GRP_MAIN
      ,tbl.VALUE
      ,tbl.NAME
FROM @tbl AS tbl
INNER JOIN DistinctNames AS dn ON tbl.NAME=dn.NAME
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 x.* FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.NAME=dn.NAME ORDER BY VALUE DESC) AS MainRec
```